# The term 'py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, django, path, environment-variables, virtual-environment

I have been trying to create a virtual environment for django project but I have been meeting the error below.

py : The term 'py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- py --version
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Attached is also the graphic of the error as it appears on my system.

I have added python to path in environmental variables yet it's not working.

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `python` instead of `py`?

Comment: Use ```python```  or ```python3```  instead of ```py```.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the python command.

Thank you @SembeiNorimaki

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have aliased the command to be `py`, the command is `python` or `python3`.

py is just the file extension

Answer (score 0):

create the alias

```
doskey py = python
```

otherwise run

```
python -m venv .venv8
```

instead of  `py -3 -m venv .venv`
to create your environment